# Pacakge name change not showing up on Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

So I made updates to an app where the KeyStore was lost somehow. I saw that I had to change the package name to something else and create a new app to release the app to the Play Store. I created a new app in the console, but every time I upload the aab file, it shows the previous package name instead of the updated name.

Here's what I mean

[image]

But my package name was changed to this

[image]

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Do you have [applicationId](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-application-id) set in your build.gradle?

Comment: You can also try to check merged manifest or use 'analyze APK' tool in Android Studio to check that the app id in your aab did change

Comment: Yeah, `applicationId` was set in the build.gradle. But I did find the key store. So it's all good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do because of the security measures that were taken to make sure there were no repeats of the same app signatures. I did find the app key for this project. So all is well.